2010 Ninja EX250, gunk in carburetor?
I just bought a 2010 Ninja EX250 and am in the process of cleaning it up and making small repairs and upgrades. Today I was draining the carburetors so I can give them a good cleaning and noticed an outward facing hole blocked solid with some crusty gunk. I poked at it with a toothpick and it crumbled a bit and I pulled something out that I can only describe as an insect larva (is this some kind of nest?):


So first of all, what is this hole? Some kind of vent? And second, should I clear it out and how? It's pretty hard to knock loose and I don't want to push any of it further inside. The bike has been working so I'm unsure how important, if at all, this hole is.

I'd think you could hit the hole with some carb cleaner to get the gunk out. Then you could see better what's there as well as if there's any damage. I think you're taking the right approach by not being too intrusive.
